# Change title size to a post title using child theme?

Tags: css, title

I remember my theme had an H1 for my Posts titles in the "Next Posts" section at the end of a post, then out of nowhere it changed to H4, how can I change it to the way it was before?
I've tried but failed everytime.

You can take a look at the "You Might Like This Too" section: http://thenoirportrait.com/2014/08/23/review-chanel-perfection-lumiere-velvet/

Thank you!

Comment: from the debug dev tools, it's an h3. Are you using wordpress ?

Comment: Oh I made a mistake, the title is indeed H3, but I meant the post titles, like: "Playful Black", those are H4

Comment: And yes, I'm using Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Okay let me explain you why having a h4 there is good and how you can change that.

You need to understand something first : In HTML, there's some title level to help the website but also software for disabled people to understand the order of the site. Who is more important etc. You must not think your title in a style way, you must think about it in a level way. So your H4 is fine.

Now if you want to change the size of your H4, you'll have to change their style in your Css. I guess you're using a wordpress, so you'll have to change it in the style.css file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your editor in wordpress at the bottom of your css file add this line.

```
h4{
   font-family: Prata;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.375rem;
  line-height: 1.875rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}
```

now all your h4 will match your H3, the other alternative is to actually go to the template that contains your post titles and change the post title from h4 to h3

Comment: Thank you it works! But as expected it also changes the to H3 in the whole website.
My first thought for this problem was to do what you just said: Go to style.css and change it, but when I try the stylesheet says this:

"Note: This css is not loaded. Parent theme uses SASS to compile and generate css files under the uploads folder.
If you need to modify the css, it is recommended that you modify and use the child theme included in the package. 
Or, you can also use the theme panel under the look & feel to customize your site or add custom CSS."

Comment: Adding it in the themes custom css should have the same effect, but I'm slightly confused to what you're asking ?